# Why do I see NotUpdatable when I invoke ResultSet.refreshRow()?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection, resultset

When I invoke following rows:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from user");
resultSet.next();
resultSet.refreshRow();//exception throws here
```

I see following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not updatable.This result set
>   must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of
>   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can
>   not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table.
>   See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.This
>   result set must come from a statement that was created with a result
>   set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one
>   table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from
>   that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more
>   details.

I wondered this exception because if read `refreshRow` method javadoc we can find following:

> The refreshRow method provides a way for an application to explicitly
>   tell the JDBC driver to refetch a row(s) from the database

Thus following direction: `database --> ResultSet`

I have following understanding:

updatable is possibility to use following direction:

```
ResultSet --> database
```

Thus I don't understand cause of problem.

please clarify.

Comment: In your statement creation, don't you have set it up with ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE?

Comment: Yes. I want only read from database!

Comment: I want to get last changes from db

Answer (score 1):

When you are using, `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`, you are getting an exception, that

> com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not updatable.This result set
>   must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of
>   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can
>   not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table.
>   See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.\

So, changing `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` to `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`, solved your problem. Correct?

Now, as I understand, you don't want to do that. Am I right? If yes, then I think you are confusing ResultSet with Database,

- ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, means read only ResultSet, not Database, similarly
- ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, means updatable ResultSet, not Database.

The method, `resultSet.refreshRow()`, suppose to update the `resultSet`, hence it rightly requires updatable `ResultSet`. I hope it's clear now.