# Difference between ResultSet TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE and TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, resultset

I am trying to understand the difference between these two methods of creating a statement:

### 1:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

### 2:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

second argument are same but first - different

from java doc:

> `resultSetType` - a result set type; one of `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`

and

> `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`
>   The constant indicating the type for a `ResultSet` object that is scrollable but generally not sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the `ResultSet`.

---

> `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`
>   The constant indicating the type for a `ResultSet` object that is scrollable and generally sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the `ResultSet`.

Thus I want to show difference between sensitivity of underlies the `ResultSet`. I want to understand what this "sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the `ResultSet`" (from Javadoc) means.

Please provide an example that demonstrates and explains the difference.

Comment: Looks like you can iterate backwards with `rowset.previous()` only if the insensitive flag is set.  Doesn't look particularly useful.

Comment: I think this option names as "scrollable" and both mentioned in question argimants are scrollable

Comment: You can scroll both, but only insensitive can be scrolled backwards.

Comment: looks like you say about ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Comment: Looks like you're right, check out FilipNguyen's answer :)

Comment: @Andomar Yeas, I checked it. please read my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 13):

Sensitivness is with regards to the underlying data (a database).

Suppose you have PEOPLE table in a database. You create insensitive statement:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

and at time 8:20 you issue a query

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE;
```

now you leave the result set open and you scroll through it using next(), previous() and absolute(int)) methods.

At 8:23 somebody updates data in PEOPLE table.

At 8:24 you are still scrolling the result set but because you have INSENSITIVE result set, you see old data.

Now comes the difference. If you had created the statement with SENSITIVE then you would see all the changes that were being done at 8:23.

Comment: I got com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable both times

Comment: please revise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582698/why-do-i-see-notupdatable-when-i-invoke-resultset-refreshrow and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582460/resultset-created-by-conection-with-type-scroll-sensitive-doesnt-see-changes-in?lq=1

Comment: @gstackoverflow Not all drivers and databases support all features that JDBC exposes, and there can be further restrictions.

Comment: I use mysql. I think it is very popular db.

Comment: Is it possible to know what mysql support?